# two digit only allowed before decimal and after decimal point in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am use an input field in html and use Javascript function.That input field accept  two digit only allowed before decimal and after decimal point in javascript.And that input field not more than 4 digit before decimal and after decimal point.

```
1.05----------accept
12.05----------accept
12.78----------accept
122.45 ----------not accept
122..45----------not accept
122.789---------not accept
```

Comment: FYI Java and JavaScript are not the same (it annoys others and it doesn't increase your chances of getting an answer)

Comment: @Hossain Please provide the code what you have attempted.

Comment: And please actually ask a question.